# Determining the count and percentage of numbers in a string (pandas)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in a dataset df which contains strings like these

```
Webs
https://www.mhouse.com/107462464135489/posts/please-lets-be-guidedun-is-where-the-code/142970213918047/
https://www.msed.com/IKONINIBWANASEEDMARCH2020.html
https://www.msed.com/
https://carrice.com/jen/stat/1241025420562178050?lang=en
```

...

I would like to determine the count and the percentage of numbers within them; so, for instance

```
Count      Percentage
15         (and the percentage compared to the length of the string)
4          ...
0          ...
19         ...
```

If I am not wrong I'd use a combination of is digit for determining the number of digits in the strings and len() for determining the length of the string, then the percentage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the number of digits in a string using `Series.str.count` with a regular expression. Additionally, you can get the length of each string in a series with `Series.str.len()`. Once you do that, calculating the percentage is straight forward!

```
df["digit_count"] = df["Webs"].str.count("\d")
df["total_characters"] = df["Webs"].str.len()
df["digit_percentage"] = df["digit_count"] / df["total_characters"] * 100

print(df)
                                                Webs  digit_count  total_characters  digit_percentage
0  https://www.mhouse.com/107462464135489/posts/p...           30               103         29.126214
1  https://www.msed.com/IKONINIBWANASEEDMARCH2020...            4                51          7.843137
2                              https://www.msed.com/            0                21          0.000000
3  https://carrice.com/jen/stat/12410254205621780...           19                56         33.928571
```

Comment: didnt know i could do `count('\d')` . Does this mean i can use any regex to check for counts? Have to try it out

Comment: Yep! `count` works with any regex, so you can simply count the pattern matches as a more readable way of doing some combination of `.str.extractall(..., expand=False)` with `.str.len()`